# Deriving some properties of a cubic without having to expand their expressions?

Tags: roots, cubics

So for a cubic equation $ax^3 +bx^2+cx+d$ with roots $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$, how do we know that

$(\alpha+\beta)(\beta+\gamma)(\alpha+\gamma)=\sum\alpha\sum\alpha\beta-\alpha\beta\gamma$

where $\sum\alpha=\alpha+\beta+\gamma$ and $\sum\alpha\beta=\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\alpha\gamma$

without having to actually expand $(\alpha+\beta)(\beta+\gamma)(\alpha+\gamma)$?? And even after we do expand it, how is it that we are able to see that it equals the right hand side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S=\alpha + \beta + \gamma$.

We have $a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$.

Then $$(S-\alpha)(S-\beta)(S-\gamma) = S^3 + \frac{b}{a}S^2 + \frac{c}{a}S + \frac{d}{a}$$

But we have $\frac{b}{a} = -S$, $\frac{c}{a} = \sum\alpha\beta$, $\frac{d}{a}=-\alpha\beta\gamma$.

SO you get the conclusion.

Comment: Alright, got it mate, thanks. Would appreciate it if you had not skipped a couple of steps and some lines of explanations though.